# .htaccess point subdomain to file

Tags: .htaccess

What I am trying to do is be able to point something like `username.domain.com` to `index.php?url=username`. I have been browsing around Google/StackOveflow and have not been able to find anything that will benefit me.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?url=%1 [L]
```

The first condition makes sure the requested host isn't **www.domain.com** or **domain.com**, the next line matches and groups the subdomain name, and the rule itself rewrites everything to `/index.php` with a query string url and the subdomain (backreferenced using **%1**).

Comment: Does not work. I am using

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?titancontent.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.titancontent.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ /index.php?url=%1 [L]`

and it says that GC could not find the page.

Comment: @BryanParmenter was missing a condition to exclude requests for `index.php`.

Comment: @BryanParmenter What URL are you attempting to go to?

Comment: http://aviance.titancontent.com - I set up in my index.php file a request to see if it hits aviance through a PHP $_GET but the page returns like it does not exist.

Comment: @BryanParmenter And if you go to http://titancontent.com/index.php?url=aviance it works? Also, when I try to lookup `aviance.titancontent.com`, it says there's no DNS entry for that hostname.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. How do I add a DNS entry. The subdomain does not exist through my host. I just want it to be able to point the sub.domain.com to domain.com/index.php?url=sub like you can point domain.com/sub to domain.com/index.php?url=sub

Comment: @BryanParmenter contact your registrar or hosting service and ask about "wildcard dns entry" or "default domain". Or just google either one of those. This really doesn't have anything to do with htaccess URI routing.